# how to avoid null while doing diff using period in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the below dataframe and I am calculating the different with the previous value using diff periods but that makes the first value as Null, is there any way to fill that value?

example:

df['cal_val'] = df.groupby('year')['val'].diff(periods=1)

current output:

```
date      year val cal_val
1/3/10    2010 12  NaN
1/6/10    2010 15  3
1/9/10    2010 18  3
1/12/10   2010 20  2
1/3/11    2011 10  NaN
1/6/11    2011 12  2
1/9/11    2011 15  3
1/12/11   2011 18  3

expected output:
    date      year val cal_val
    1/3/10    2010 12  12
    1/6/10    2010 15  3
    1/9/10    2010 18  3
    1/12/10   2010 20  2
    1/3/11    2011 10  10
    1/6/11    2011 12  2
    1/9/11    2011 15  3
    1/12/11   2011 18  3
```

Comment: Use `df['cal_val'] = df.groupby('year')['val'].diff(periods=1).fillna(df['val'])`

Comment: df.groupby('year')['val'].diff(periods=1).ffill(axis=1)